# choosing which POCO to serialize to based on a condition

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, serialization

I want to serialize a nested object in a json document to a POCO (plain old c# object) based on a field in the "meta" area of that object but I don't know how to do this.

For example say I have the following doc:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "type": "beer",
  "_source": {
     "name": "myBeer",
     "brewery": "myBrewery", 
     "address": "blah"
  }
}
```

with this format the source field would map to another POCO with the fields name, brewery and address.

now say that I have another doc in the same index with the following fields:

```
{
  "id": 345,
  "type": "brewery",
  "_source": {
    "name": "mybrewery",
    "date": "somedate", 
    "city": "somecity"
  }
}
```

so based on the type variable of the document, the _source information should be serialized to a different POCO.

I know that `ShouldSerialize` method works for properties within a class, so is there something similar to that that will work for classes? basically that will serialize a json object to a specific POCO based on a condition?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the contract informations to resolve the right type from the outer meta informations.

Write a converter class that will do the whole job for you:

```
public class DocConverter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<MetaInformation, object>> deserializers = new Dictionary<string, Func<MetaInformation, object>>();
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>> serializers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>();

    private class MetaInformation
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "id" )]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "type" )]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "_source" )]
        public object Source { get; set; }
    }

    public void Register<Source, SourceData>( string contractName, Func<Source, Tuple<int,SourceData>> converter, Func<<Tuple<int, SourceData>, Source> reverter )
        where Source : class
        where SourceData : class
    {
        deserializers.Add( contractName,
            ( m ) =>
            {
                SourceData data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SourceData>( m.Source.ToString() );
                return reverter( Tuple.Create( m.Id, data ) );                    
            } );

        serializers.Add( typeof( Source ),
            ( o ) =>
            {   
                var data = converter( (Source) o );
                var meta = new MetaInformation { Id = data.Item1, Type = contractName, Source = data.Item2, };
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( meta );
            } );
    }

    public string Serialize( object source )
    {
        return serializers[ source.GetType() ]( source );
    }

    public object Deserialize( string jsonData )
    {
        var meta = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MetaInformation>( jsonData );
        return deserializers[ meta.Type ]( meta );
    }
}
```

For serialization we need to define the structure/contract of the inner data

```
public class BeerSource
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "name" )]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "brewery" )]
    public string Brewery { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "address" )]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class BrewerySource
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "name" )]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "date" )]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty( "city" )]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

The real classes

```
public class Beer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Brewery { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Brewery
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And after all, we only register the contract name, converter and reverter

```
var conv = new DocConverter();
conv.Register<Beer, BeerSource>( 
    "beer", 
    ( o ) => Tuple.Create( o.Id, new BeerSource { Name = o.Name, Brewery = o.Brewery, Address = o.Address, } ), 
    ( t ) => new Beer { Id = t.Item1, Name = t.Item2.Name, Brewery = t.Item2.Brewery, Address = t.Item2.Address, } );
conv.Register<Brewery, BrewerySource>( 
    "brewery", 
    ( o ) => Tuple.Create( o.Id, new BrewerySource { Name = o.Name, Date = o.Date, City = o.City, } ), 
    ( t ) => new Brewery { Id = t.Item1, Name = t.Item2.Name, Date = t.Item2.Date, City = t.Item2.City, } );
```

and now we have a very small footprint to use it

```
object source;
object result;
string jsonData;

source = new Beer { Id = 123, Name = "myBeer", Brewery = "myBrewery", Address = "blah", };
jsonData = conv.Serialize( source );
// check the JSON result
Console.WriteLine( jsonData );
result = conv.Deserialize( jsonData );
// check the result type
Console.WriteLine( result.GetType().ToString() );

source = new Brewery { Id = 456, Name = "myBrewery", Date = "somedate", City = "somecity", };
jsonData = conv.Serialize( source );
// check the JSON result
Console.WriteLine( jsonData );
result = conv.Deserialize( jsonData );
// check the result type
Console.WriteLine( result.GetType().ToString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this when serializing inherited types. The serializer will automatically add meta properties to the JSON doc which will help to deserialize to the correct type. You might have to adjust some settings for this this to happen, though. Tell us what serializer you are using so someone can help you with the specifics there.

However, you should not do this anyway. Those meta propeties are specific to the serializer being used. E.g. the default JSON serializer of Web API 2 adds a property called "`$type`" whereas the Data Contract JSON serializer adds a property called "`__type`". This means that you are introducing a tight coupling between JSON provider and JSON consumer -- both are forced to use the same serializer.

Create two different types for `_source` instead: one for breweries and one for beers. This will save you and every stakeholder lots of trouble.